# `fs.readdir` returning undefined in tests

Tags: node.js, fs

Im my `getFiles` module I have the method `_get` to fetch the files in a directory. This will then be used to read the contents of each file and upload them to a S3 bucket. However, when I run the tests for `getFiles`, the value of `files` is `undefined`.

What am I missing here?

the file where my module is, `readDirectory.js`:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

var _getFiles = {};

_getFiles._get = function (path, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, function (error, files) {
        console.log(path);
        console.log(files);
        callback(files);
    });
};

module.exports = _getFiles;
```

tests using `mocha`, `chai` and `sion`:

```
describe("readDirectory run", function () {
    var testedModule, callbackSpy, readFileStub;

    before(function () {

        readFileStub = sinon.stub();

        callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

        testedModule = require('../readDirectory.js');

        mockDir({
            tmp: {
                images: {
                    "thumb_test.txt": "thumbnail pic",
                    "small_test.txt": "small pic",
                    "medium_test.txt": "medium pic"
                }
            }
        });
    });

    after(function () {
        mockDir.restore();
    });

    it("returns list of files", function () {
        testedModule._get(mockDir, function () {console.log(files);});
    });
});
```

This is the result of the test, which is not testing anything yet except running the code:

```
readDirectory run
    ✓ returns list of files
{ [Function: mock]
  restore: [Function],
  fs: [Function],
  file: [Function],
  directory: [Function],
  symlink: [Function] }
undefined
```

Comment: You haven't passed `files` as an argument to your callback. `testedModule._get(mockDir, function (files) {`

Comment: It now returns `readDirectory run
    ✓ returns list of files
Path: function mock(config) {
  var system = FileSystem.create(config);
  var binding = new Binding(system);
  setBinding(binding, binding.Stats);
}
undefined
undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Ben Fortune's answer was deterministic in reaching the solution, however not complete.

I was using the mocked directory incorrectly when passing it in to the tested module. So instead of what I have in the question, it should be:

```
....
it("returns list of files", function () {
        testedModule._get("tmp/images/", function (files) {
            console.log("Files from callback, %s", files);
        });
    });
....
```

Please note how I no longer pass the object `mockDir` as the first argument to `testedModule`, but instead the actual path to the directory mock I have created, `tmp/images/`